# Что лучше использовать для загрузки файлов на FTP сервер?

Tags: c#

Подскажите что лучше использовать для загрузки файлов до 100МБ на FTP сервер?

1 - Webclient

2 - FtpWebRequest

Есть проблемы с 1: у меня на сервере появляются архив но они получаются как битые (нельзя посмотреть)

Вот код:

```
public static void FTPReply()
    {
        try
        {
            using (WebClient FileFtp = new WebClient())
            {
                FileFtp.BaseAddress = "ftp://site.ru";FileFtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Login", "Password");
                string[] fileNames = new string[] {  };
                foreach (string file in fileNames)
                {
                    FileFtp.UploadFile(new Uri("ftp://site.ru/public_html/" + Path.GetFileName(file)), file);
                }
            }        
        } catch { }
    }
```

Подскажите что лучше использовать для загрузки файлов?!

Comment: Как именно они битые?

Comment: Убирай этот поганый catch и разбирайся.